# How can I put a solid border around a button to show it has focus without an enclosing <div>?

Tags: html, css

I realize I can add a border around a button and have it set to a width but is there a way that I can add a solid border around that to show that the button has focus.

Note that I am looking to have a solid one color (not fading) border. Also I would like the border not to upset the spacing if I have a few buttons in a row? I know one solution is for me to put `<div>` with border around every button and set the border of that div but I am hoping there is a way to do this without including each button in a div.

```
<button>a</button>
<button class="primary">b</button>
<button>c</button>
```

In this case I would like the space between button a, b and c to be the same and the middle button to have a solid area around it.

Comment: please upload fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an  [`outline`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/outline). Example:

```
button:focus {outline:3px solid red}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/etgamfyr/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
border:2px solid;
```

check here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcd30grt/1/)

**update** check here [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcd30grt/3/)

Comment: My buttons already have a border. I would like to add a focus area around that if possible.